# navigation bar wouldn't displayed in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have little problem with `UIsearchBarController`. When I tap on 
search bar it always shows white color at navigation bar. I want navigation bar at there.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
   {
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
   }
 }

 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
   [self addSearching];
  }


-(void)addSearching
 {
   searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
   searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
   searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
   searchResultsController.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
   searchResultsController.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
   searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

   searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
   searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

   searchController.delegate = self;
   searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
   searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

   searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search Members";
   [searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];


   //self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed

   self.memberTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
}
```

And output is:

[image]

Comment: Use `searchResultsController.navigationBar.hidden = YES`

Comment: You want navigation bar or not?

Comment: @Poles: yes i need it. Its missing at there.

Comment: Then you should use `searchResultsController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;` //or UIBarStyleBlack

Comment: @Poles: not working with this, same result.

Comment: Use `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` in `viewDidLoad` and let me know if the space gone or not.

Comment: @Poles: Already have added  :(

Comment: I don't find it in your question. By the way did it work?